# Why is the DNS still working?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

i set up a server with Flask on raspberrypi and created 2 subdomains (ex: 123.ddns.net, 456.duckdns.com).
I configured my router for port forwarding and DNS configuration (DynDNS) and i also use ddclient.
The problem is: when i configure my router and ddclient for 123.ddns.net and start the server it works fine (points to my home pc). Then i change the configuration for 456.duckdns.com and start the server and it works, but at the same time it still works for 123.ddns.net!

When i connect to 123.ddns.net or 456.duckdns.com on my browser it will show me the same results. As if 123.ddns.net is still pointing to my router..

Is it a DNS cache problem or is there an other explanation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed is still pointing to your router.

DynDNS does not maintain a persistent "live" connection. Your router only uses ddclient to send periodic updates (in case your IP address changes), but the actual DNS records on your provider's servers actually are completely static: they will stay there **until something deletes them.**

Generally, when you configure a router for a new DynDNS provider, it won't bother cleaning up information at the old provider: it just overwrites the old settings with the new ones and that's it. (I'm not sure if most providers even *allow* the client to outright delete the hostname through their "updating" API.)

So that means your old hostname could remain active and pointing to the same address forever unless you go to the control panel and delete it (or unless the provider itself deletes your account as "inactive"). Simply turning ddclient off will not make it go away.

---

That said, DNS caching can possibly contribute to this as well – but unlikely to be the cause, as the whole thing about DynDNS services is that they tend to use very low caching TTLs, usually ranging from seconds to minutes, so that users would see their "dynamic" updates as soon as possible.